# XSL using multiple node attributes

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I am new to all this and have tried various routes and variations to get the data into my table but I am unable to get the second and third dimension node attribute. I have obviously got something wrong in either the attribute value selection or the template use as I just get a repeat of the first attribute for each column.

My XML input is:

```
<nodes>
  <node name="Server Dashboard">
    <children>
      <node name="Server Dashboard">
        <dimension name="Performance" status="20" id="10" >null</dimension>
        <dimension name="System" status="10" id="20" >null</dimension>
        <dimension name="Availability" status="30" id="30" >null</dimension>
        <children>
          <node name="SERVER 1">
            <dimension name="Performance" status="20" id="10" >null</dimension>
            <dimension name="System" status="10" id="20" >null</dimension>
            <dimension name="Availability" status="30" id="30" >null</dimension>
            <children>
            </children>
          </node>
          <node name="SERVER 2">
            <dimension name="Performance" status="20" id="10" >null</dimension>
            <dimension name="System" status="10" id="20" >null</dimension>
            <dimension name="Availability" status="30" id="30" >null</dimension>
            <children>
            </children>
          </node>
        </children>
      </node>
    </children>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

And I am trying to get an output like

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <th>System</th>
      <th>Performance</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Availability</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>SERVER 1</td>
      <td>20</td>   
      <td>10</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>SERVER 2</td>
      <td>20</td>   
      <td>10</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And currently I have the xsl of which almost gets me there but not quite as it seems not to loop on the dimension nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
        <th>System</th>
        <th>Performance</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Availability</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="nodes/node/children/node/children/node"> 
      <tr> 
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="dimension/@Status[//@id='10']"/></td>   
        <td><xsl:value-of select="dimension/@status[//@id='20']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="dimension/@status[//@id='30']"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

My final aim is to replace the status number with a coloured cell or .gif, but baby steps at the moment.
Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Main point is to select the dimension by id attribute value first, then select the status attribute value.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
            <tr> 
                <th>System</th>
                <th>Performance</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Availability</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="nodes/node/children/node/children/node"> 
            <tr> 
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="dimension[@id='10']/@status"/></td>   
                <td><xsl:value-of select="dimension[@id='20']/@status"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="dimension[@id='30']/@status"/></td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
      </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Wonderful and great explanation too.